# invert or transpose

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization

Is this correct:

> When finding the diagonalization of a matrix $A$ of the form $QDQ^{-1}$ then if you normalize your eigenvectors instead of having to invert $Q$, you could just take $Q^t$.

Just because I did not know what so search for online.

Comment: You can try "orthogonal diagonalization."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not always correct! The inverse $Q^{-1}$ is equal to $Q^T$ only for an **orthogonal** matrix. A matrix $A$ is diagonalizable via an orthogonal matrix $Q$ i.e.
$$A=QDQ^T$$
only if $A$ is **symmetric**.

Comment: Also note that if $A$ has distinct eigenvalues then the eigenvectors will be orthogonal "automatically".  If $A$ has repeated eigenvalues then it is still possible to find orthogonal eigenvectors, but you may have to do a bit of work, for example using the Gram-Schmidt process.

Comment: @David long story short, the subspaces spanned by eigenvectors are orthogonal.

Comment: @AlgebraicPavel true, but the point I want to make is that sometimes you get your orthogonal basis vectors with pretty much no work, sometimes you don't.